# Golang pointer receiver not updating as expected

Tags: algorithm, go, binary-tree

I am implementing node deletion in binary search tree. I have implemented a method which look good (at algorithm standpoint). But do not work. After spending hours trying to understand why, I would love to get some help from you.

BST definition

```
    type Node struct {
    Data  int
    Left  *Node
    Right *Node
}
```

Helper methods (they have been tested and works)

```
// New returns a pointer to a mew node (like the new construct in Go)
func New(data int) *Node {
    return &Node{Data: data}
}

// Find checks whether some data exist in the bst and returns the corresponding node
func (bst *Node) Find(data int) *Node {
    if bst == nil {
        return bst
    }
    if bst.Data == data {
        return bst
    }
    if data < bst.Data {
        return bst.Left.Find(data)
    }
    return bst.Right.Find(data)
}

// Min returns the smallest element in a bst
func (bst *Node) Min() *Node {
    if bst == nil {
        return nil
    }
    current := bst
    for current.Left != nil {
        current = current.Left
    }
    return current
}
```

The non working method

```
// Delete removes a key from the binary tree
func (bst *Node) Delete(data int) *Node {
    if bst == nil {
        return bst
    }
    current := bst
    toDelete := current.Find(data)
    if toDelete == nil {
        return current
    }
    if toDelete.Right == nil && toDelete.Left != nil {
        toDelete = toDelete.Left
        return current
    }
    if toDelete.Right != nil && toDelete.Left == nil {
        toDelete = toDelete.Right
        return current
    }
    inOrderSuccessor := toDelete.Right.Min()
    toDelete = inOrderSuccessor
    return current
}
```

Test

```
func main() {
    root := bst.New(8)
    root.Left = bst.New(3)
    root.Right = bst.New(10)
    root.Left.Left = bst.New(1)
    root.Left.Right = bst.New(6)
    fmt.Println(root.InOrder())
    root = root.Delete(3)
    fmt.Println(root.InOrder())
}

output
1->3->6->8->10->
1->3->6->8->10->
```

There is something wrong in the Delete method but I could not understand why.

This code can be run in the playground here https://go.dev/play/p/oJZMOCp2BXL

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you think that

```
toDelete = toDelete.Left
```

overwrites data that is stored where `toDelete` points to.
But this operation will just assign a new pointer to `toDelete`variable. To overwrite data that is stored in memory you need to dereference the pointer:

```
*toDelete = *toDelete.Left
```

You can look at this example https://go.dev/play/p/M62hd3lpHXk and see the difference in a simpler case.